# How does one style element within a label say?

Tags: asp.net, css

Lets say I have an asp.net label that has the value:

Label1.Text = "Hello my name is Robert, the ID value is 20"

and I wanted to apply bold to the name "Robert" and the ID "20".

And green for his name and red for the value...
I cannot apply a CSS style to the entire Label because it would make every text value a certain style. How can I apply CSS to something like this?  I dont want to embed `<strong>` tags within the label like this:

`Label1.Text = "Hello my name is <strong>Robert</strong>..."`

Comment: I don't think this can be done, can't wait to see what'll come up! :)

Comment: @maxbeaudoin - currently I use a bunch of span tags, I thought there may be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark up the name and the ID in some way.

Example:

```
Label1.Text = "Hello my name is <span class=""name"">Robert</span>, the ID value is <span class=""id"">20</span>"
```

CSS

```
#label1 .name {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#label1 .id {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: That's waht i am currently doing, ok as long as that is what everyone else is doing...

Comment: Yes, that's what we're used to and it probably won't change before regular exporessions comes to CSS ;o)

Answer (score 1):

- You could embed `<span>` which you then apply styles to
- You use seperate labels

Usually you wouldn't set content in code behind like this, but if it needs to be dynamic you would allow the insertion of HTML.

Comment: I think each label is supposed to be atomic.  This means that is is consistent throughout, and as soon as you want to separate styles you should separate labels.  It's basically the result of the leaky abstraction caused by ASP.NET when converting to HTML.

Comment: Yes understandable, but then you'd have to deal with a whole slew of other disasters if you are dealing with multiple labels when all you need is a sentence.  When I say disasters, I mean additional formatting, spacing, alignment, etc just to make it look right.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to apply any kind of style without wrapping the text with some kind of element. (`span`, `strong`, `em`, etc..)

Like *m.edmondson* said, you will have to :

- Wrap the values you want to color with elements and then apply styles to them, or...
- Use separate labels to recreate your message and apply styles to the ones containing the values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot, you probably end up making 2 different labels, something like this:

```
<div>
Hello my name is <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" CssClass="Name" /> and the ID value is <asp:Label ID="IDValue" runat="server" CssClass="IDValue" />
</div>
```

Then set the Texts of both labels in the code behind. Alternatively you could also set the CssClass in the code behind if you want.